# Erorr: no operator ">>" matches these arguments

Tags: c++, cin

```
int main()
{ 
char* NamePointer = new char;


std::cout << "Enter the file you want to edit (MUST BE IN THE PROJECT'S DIRECTORY): ";
std::cin >> &NamePointer;

const char* FileName = NamePointer;
delete &NamePointer;


return 0;
}
```

This returns me the error in the title:

```
std::cin >> &NamePointer;
```

Any ideas? This is probably something simple I'm missing, but when I looked it up I didn't get my answer.

<strike>JUST FIXED IT, SORRY FOR BOTHERING! I took out the "&" in "&NamePointer".</strike>

Yeah I just found out another way of doing this using c_str(). Sorry!

Comment: Just removing the `&` didn't fix it, It still is broken.Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have:

```
std::cin >> NamePointer;
```

Also, you are just allocating an memory of one character, probably you meant:

```
char* NamePointer = new char[MAX_SIZE];
```

and dellocate it as:

```
delete []NamePointer;
```

Note that the, C++ way of doing this is to simply use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) which takes care of the problem of buffer overflows you get with using `char*`:

```
std::string Name;
std::cin >> Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the *address of* operator here. Simply:

```
std::cin >> NamePointer;
```

---

Some other things I've noticed:

```
char* NamePointer = new char;
```

You probably want more space than just one character. A simple start may be a large static allocation:

```
char NamePointer[1024];
```

In which case, you omit the `delete` statement at the end (which also doesn't use an *address of* operator, by the way).