# cin >> "no operator matches these operands"

Tags: c++, cin

I've been working on a C++ project in visual studio 2012 console mode and I keep getting this strange persistent error with the `cin` function.

Under the `>>` I get a red line and the program tells me `no operator matches these operands`.
I have initialized all the array elements in a separate method.

Here's a snippet example (The actual code contains many more variables):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    cout << "For taxi: " << i+1 << "Please input the taxi rank they are currently parked at, if at all ('Train Station', 'South Walls' or 'Chell Road')" << endl;
    cin >> allTaxiDetails[i].taxiRank;
}
```

---

`allTaxiDetails` is an array, of data type "`taxiDetails`" which is this structure:

```
struct taxiDetails { 
    string taxiDriverSurname; 
    int taxiID; 
    int taxiCoordinates; 
    int numberOfSeats; 
    bool taxiContainsCustomerYesNo; 
    bool WheelChairAccessibleVehicle; 
    string taxiRank; 
    fareDetails fareDetailsForTaxi; 
    bool taxiAvaliable; 
};
```

Comment: Not enough information. What is the type of `allTaxiDetails[i].taxiRank`?

Comment: allTaxiDetails is an array, of data type "taxiDetails" which is this structure:
struct taxiDetails
{    
string taxiDriverSurname;
int taxiID;
int taxiCoordinates;
int numberOfSeats;
bool taxiContainsCustomerYesNo;
bool WheelChairAccessibleVehicle;
string taxiRank;
fareDetails fareDetailsForTaxi;
bool taxiAvaliable;
};

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erorr: no operator ">>" matches these arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004499/erorr-no-operator-matches-these-arguments)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, sorry =(

Comment: Did you include `iostream`?

Comment: Try adding: #include <string>

Answer (score 31):

Issue is saying that `string` doesn't have the `operator>>` method, but it does...

1. Did you forget `#include <string>` at the top of that file?
2. Maybe try using `getline(std::cin, allTaxiDetails[I].taxiRank, '\n');`.
3. Define `operator>>` for your struct.

Answer (score 10):

It seems you are trying to read an object of type `std::string` for which you somehow obtained the class definition (e.g. by including `<iostream>`) but you didn't get all the necessary operations! Make sure you are including `<string>`:

```
#include <string>
// ...
```

It is quite common that some headers provide definitions of some other classes but actually don't use the entire header to get the definitions. Since `std::string` is in some places needed to declare IOStreams it is fairly likely that it will be defined but probably not by including its full header.

Comment: He's not trying to read in the entire struct, `taxiRank` is a string.

Comment: Thank you guys =) I'll try your suggestions now and feedback asap.

Comment: Mark it as the answer, then. Glad we could help.

Comment: @user3163612: Mark Keeler's response as the accepted answer: he stated the problem before I did!

Answer (score 7):

I believe forget  *#include < string >* this critical header is the error source. It happened to me as a beginner of C++.